# Getting SSLPeerUnverifiedException in Android

Tags: android, ssl, https, http-post

i am getting SSL Peer Unverified Exception when i try to connect using HTTPs Connection.
I am new to HTTPs. 
My code is :

```
HostnameVerifier hostnameVerifier = org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER;

DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
SchemeRegistry registry = new SchemeRegistry();
SSLSocketFactory socketFactory = SSLSocketFactory.getSocketFactory();
socketFactory.setHostnameVerifier((X509HostnameVerifier) hostnameVerifier);
registry.register(new Scheme("https", socketFactory, 443));
SingleClientConnManager mgr = new SingleClientConnManager(client.getParams(), registry);
DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(mgr, client.getParams());                  HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(hostnameVerifier);
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("https://server.example.com/Login");
List<BasicNameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<BasicNameValuePair>(
                            2);
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("LoginId",uname));
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Password",pass));
try {
httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httppost);
if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200) {

}               
Log.i("zacharia", "Response :"+EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()));
} catch (Exception e) {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The SSL Peer Unverified Exception could be thrown for several reasons, the most common is when the certificate sent by the server is a self signed certificate and not a certificate signed by authorized CA, if that's the issue the common approach in android is adding the certificate to the Trusted Certificates chain and then making the request as follows:

```
KeyStore selfsignedKeys = KeyStore.getInstance("BKS");
selfsignedKeys.load(context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.selfsignedcertsbks),
"genericPassword".toCharArray());
TrustManagerFactory trustMgr = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
trustMgr.init(selfsignedKeys);
SSLContext selfsignedSSLcontext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
selfsignedSSLcontext.init(null, trustMgr.getTrustManagers(), new SecureRandom());
HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(selfsignedSSLcontext.getSocketFactory());
URL serverURL = new URL("https://server.example.com/endpointTest");
HttpsURLConnection serverConn = (HttpsURLConnection)serverURL.openConnection();
```

Take on count that this approach is only when you are sure the certificate not signed by a CA, and in order to make it work you need to have the certificate it self, put it in a BKS keystore (for android to read it) and then open an HttpURLConnection using the SSL context that "accepts" that self signed certificate, because the DefaultHttpClient will not handle those requests based on the Default SSLContext.

If you want to learn more about SSL i recommend you to read the book "Application Security for the Android Platform" by Jeff Six Editorial O'Reilly...

Regards!